# How to access a variable from constructor outside of method in python

Tags: python

```
class A(): 
   B: str = "no"
```

```
class test(A): 
   a = None
   def __init__(self, val): 
       self.a = val
   
   if self.a == "test":
      B = "yes"
```

```
t = test("test")
print(t.B)
```

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

**self.a** shows an error so how can I access **a** which was assigned a value in the constractor out side of a method inside the class?

Comment: Just write `a`, self can only be used on an instance

Comment: @Mandera no, that won't work (as they expect) and that's incorrect, `self` just references the instance, the name `self` has to be defined somewhere, like a local name in a method (first parameter), also there's no way to access it like that, `a` is an instance attribute, it has to be accessed through that instance

Comment: [Sure it works](https://gist.github.com/Mandera/e8955f1bca0327c8b123f5cee402e808). No, `a` is both a class instance and an instance attribute. His question was to use logic inside the class outside the method. It's a very strange question and `self.a = "test"` will not affect it (Ignoring the missing `self` in the `__init__` signature)

Comment: You can't.  The `a` that is assigned to in the ctor is different to the `a`  available inside the class.

Comment: while you're at it your constructor needs `self` as its first argument, as @Mandera notes.  But why would you want to do this?  Logic either belongs on the instance, or the class, but not both---otherwise the encapsulation is broken.

Comment: In my original code test class inherits another class and from that class there are parameters that I need to change based on the value of self.a using if case so what do you suggest I do? I have also edited the question to illustrate my point more

Comment: @Bemhreth why do you want to change parent's attribute from child? that really shouldn't happen

Comment: @Matiiss the open source project am working on has that structure so I don't have a choice

Comment: @Bemhreth has what structure? changing parent attributes from child?

Comment: @Matiiss yes that

Answer (score 1):

1. Because you are making class object u need to define the object name used

```
class test():
    def __init__(self):
```

2. You want to access your attribute, you cant access outside of method so

```
class test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "test"
        if self.a == "test":
            pass
```

or you can create another method that process that

```
class test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "test"
        self.access_a()
                
    def access_a(self):
        if self.a == "test":
            print("do something")
            pass
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for (given that your example defines an instance attribute) is quite frankly not possible, you can't access an instance attribute without referencing that instance and you can't reference an instance of a class in its body.

What could be done is changing the class attribute from the constructor but that would be pointless because all code in the body of the class gets executed first so such a check (as in your provided sample) would be pointless anyways.